# Breeze is not storing the right value (that is set in code) when saving during entityChanged event

Tags: entity-framework, knockout.js, typescript, breeze, kogrid

I'm have a Breeze, Typescript, MVC 5.2, Knockout, Entity Framework webapp. I try to update a value of an User entity when the user clicks on a row in a grid (kogrid). The value is (should be) saved in the entityChanged eventhandler, but in Fiddler I see that the property value has not changed and the entityAspect.entityState is set to Modified (!) The originalValuesMap has the old TenantId and is the only value in the map.

I subscribe to the entity changed event like this:

```
this.EntityManager.entityChanged.subscribe((data: breeze.EntityChangedEventArgs) => {
    if (data.entityAction == breeze.EntityAction.PropertyChange) {
                return this.EntityManager.saveChanges(<breeze.Entity[]> new Array(data.entity))
                    .fail((error) => alert("Failed. " + error));}

        });
```

The data arrives correctly a the eventhandler. A savechanges call is made, but the changed value (tenantId) has not changed.

The eventhandler for the rowclick is as follows:

```
ViewModel).OnRowClick = (tenantId: KnockoutObservable<System.IGuid>, viewModel: Imp.Scripts._TenantListViewModel) => {
        entityManager.fetchEntityByKey("User", viewModel.Settings().CurrentUser().UserId(), false)
        .then(entityKeyResult => {
            (<Imp.Classes.UserBreeze>entityKeyResult.entity).CurrentTenantId(tenantId());
            //entityManager.saveChanges(<breeze.Entity[]> new Array(entityKeyResult.entity));
         })
        .fail((error)=> alert("Error setting current tenant. " + error));});
```

When I disable the entityChanged subscription and enable the comment out line entityManager.saveChanges.... the entity is saved correctly. If I uncomment the line, but keep the subscription, it does not work.

How can I save the changed entity automatically after it changes?

EDIT:
Workaround is to disable the entityChanged eventhandler temporarily before changing the value CurrentTenantId on the current user, save the entity manually and re-subscribe to the entityChanged event.
But this solution smells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few suggestions:

1. Consider throttling the saves if propertychanged events are fired frequently.  Knockout has a [rate limiting extender](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/rateLimit-observable.html) for this purpose.
2. You may also want to consider using [breeze save queuing plugin](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/concurrent-saves#savequeuing) so you don't need to worry about overlapping save calls as much.
3. To troubleshoot the save issue, try adding the following code immediately before calling saveChanges:

`if (data.entityAction === breeze.EntityAction.PropertyChange) {
    var pcArgs = <breeze.PropertyChangedEventArgs>data.args;
    console.log('Property Changed.  PropertyName: ' + pcArgs.propertyName + '; Old Value: ' + (pcArgs.oldValue ? pcArgs.oldValue.toString() : 'null') + '; New Value: ' + (pcArgs.newValue ? pcArgs.newValue.toString() : 'null') + ';');
}`

Comment: I've changed your code to show entitytype:

Property Changed.  PropertyName: CurrentTenantEntity type: UserPoco:#Imp.Persistent; Old Value: [object Object]; New Value: [object Object];
Property Changed.  PropertyName: CurrentTenantIdEntity type: UserPoco:#Imp.Persistent; Old Value: 534b1611-9f36-47b5-9e20-d959aa0d97eb; New Value: db626552-b8c9-4682-a8ea-5945a54152f0;

SaveQueuing was already on and I've set rateLimit to 500ms:

public CurrentUser: KnockoutObservable<Imp.Persistent.UserBreeze> = ko.observable<Imp.Persistent.UserBreeze>().extend({rateLimit: 500});

Unfortunately problem remains

Comment: this means the save is occurring prior to CurrentTenantId being assigned right?  what if you wrap the saveChanges line like so:  setTimeout(...save changes code..., 0);

Comment: I'd don't think this means that the save is occurring prior to the CurrenTenantId being assigned. The code is called because the CurrentTenantId is being assigned in the OnRowClick event handler. However, the SetTimeOut did do the trick!! THANKS! I cannot explain why a timeout that is set to zero solves my issue.

Comment: What I think is happening is the propertychanged event related to the "CurrentTenantEntity" property fires, triggering the save, then the "CurrentTenantId" property is assigned, triggering the second propertychanged event.  The settimeout trick allows both properties to be assigned before the save is invoked.